# How to check logged in user is male or female mysql and codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**controller code  want to check my logged in user is male or female for matrimony**

```
  public function profile() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            //get session Id 
            $uname = $this->session->userdata();

            //get Data from db
            $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();

            if ($row = $uname) {
                //session id and db id matched 
                $session_id = $this->session->userdata();

                //here i want to check login user is male or female
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain your code properly

Comment: did have gender column in your db ?

Comment: yes  there for asking this quation

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your logic to ask this question, its obvious that you will get gender specific information from DB and set all user data to your session, and  display get your desired info by getting from session.

Set to Session:

```
$_SESSION["gender"] = "male";
$_SESSION["age"] = "28";
```

And Get from Session:

```
<?php
   echo "Gender is " .$_SESSION["gender"];
?>
```